ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pipenv (from versions: none), ERROR: No matching distribution found for pipenv
Im pretty new to python and trying to learn about Django. Im taking a course called code with mosh and he's telling me to install pipenv using the command: "pip3 install pipenv". Im on a Mac and the errors i'm getting are: "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pipenv (from versions: none), ERROR: No matching distribution found for pipenv". This isn't the only time I've gotten this problem, because it happens every time I try to install a new package.
Again I'm new to programming in general and I don't know much about this topic. i've tried ChatGPT, but it's no use, I've tried searching it up, but it's no use, and I've tried asking my dad but it's no use because he only knows c#. Can anyone help me?

maybe helpful or related ssl module in Python is not available on macos

Can you post the complete error message?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Pipenv documentation recommends installing pipenv on most platforms using the following command:
pip install pipenv --user 

Or in your case, use
pip3 install pipenv --user

